# Identification of a piece, 1x1 bar piece with studs and handle

Tags: part-identification

[image]

Sorry for the small image, but does anyone know what number that piece is?

Comment: I don't want to start anything, but as the rabid editor/moderator of the site, I think it would be good if you would give titles for your questions that show what you are asking about a little better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [4599b - Tap 1x1 without hole in end](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?P=4599b#T=C).

[image]